# Tcl 8.6.9 script picking up incorrect File name

Tags: file, tcl, config

I have been seeing this error when running Tcl scripts on Tcl version 8.6.9. The Executive Software has been picking up the .tcl file name as "--.conf.tcl" instead of "System.conf.tcl".

```
FAILED SCRIPT:
couldn't read file C:/Test/--.conf.tcl: no such file or directory
```

And the code stops after this, not too sure why this is happening. Could anyone guide me please?

I tried going to "System.conf.tcl" to check if I had mistyped it as "--.conf.tcl". But that was not the case - everything looked ok.
No typos in the scripts overall.

Comment: Need a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What is "The Executive Software"?

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specific. The Executive Software is my version of a public class which calls all the script files that need to be run for final execution. When executing this public class script, it is picking up one the Tcl script file names as "--.conf.tcl" instead of "System.conf.tcl", I don't understand why. Hope that makes sense, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: What Tcl command do you use to call up these files?

Comment: Try looking for places where there is a `--`; in one, I'm guessing it is getting misinterpreted.